# ExpiresByType not working but <FilesMatch> IS in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, caching, mod-expires

I've been rather perplexed by this and was hoping someone might be able to shed some light.

In my htaccess file, I have:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType text/html  "access plus 4 hours"
</IfModule>
```

However, it doesnt seem to be working when I check the headers.
I get *"no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"*

But if I use THIS code:

```
# 4 HOURS
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=14400, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

It DOES pick up the cache.
*max-age=14400, must-revalidate*

Am I missing something?  Is one for the server and one for the browser? I mean, I'd prefer to use the first since it came with boilerplate if they are both the same.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already have the solution but are you sure mod_expire is enabled on your server? On ubuntu `sudo apache2ctl -M`.

You can also try to comment out `<IfModule mod_expires.c>` and `</IfModule>` and restart apache. It will crash if `mod_expires` is not enabled.

To enable mod_expire:

> sudo a2enmod expires

mod_expires will create the `Expire` header and should modify the `max-age=14400` part of the `Cache-Control` header only. For the `must-revalidate` part you will have to use `Header`.